# android internal storage data recovery in 4.4.2

Tags: android, data-recovery

I am trying to recover deleted photos from android 4.4.2 lg g2's internal storage, As I cannot connect the internal storage as a USB Mass Storage or as an Disk Drive, I cannot run any of the data recovery software.

If there are possibilities to connect as an USB Mass Storage or Disk Drive, or if there is totally different method to achieve this, Please let me know.

Edit : Wondershare Dr.Fone for android seems to be the only software that can scan, but it does not retrieve encrypted Images.

Answer (score 0):

The program that I would use at work to recover deleted files or files from a failing hard drive is called Disk Drill. The one we used was for OS X but it looks like there is also a version from windows.

Although from the years of use I had with it, it was able to recover files that were deleted as long as that part of the disk had not been written over again. It will scan the disk and literally grab every file it can, even things that might be half way deleted or corrupt. If the device was encrypted it might have a more difficult time getting files back. I have not used it on a android devices but I would give it a shot.